# Static Resource in Worklight Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

Is it possible for me to put some static resources such as HTML or text file on Worklight server so that I can retrieve them by an adapter or through an URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the host machine that you have your application server installed there and Worklight Server deployed onto it?

1. In theory you could you save files somewhere on the machine, in some publicly accessible folder and have your adapters point there. However,
2. Worklight Server itself is not meant to be a backend server, you don't save things in Worklight Server itself for consumption. Worklight Server is a conduit, using adapters, between apps and backend system. Don't mix the two.